# Exit nested for loop in python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I wanted to search through a csv file that will look up keywords from a list within the first two columns. I've managed to get it to work when a key word is found, but wanted to have a message if no keywords found. Unfortunately the message "not found" comes out four times. I just wanted this to come out once. Please can you help? What it's doing is going around each key word again.

```
import csv
keywords=["none","blank","off","screen","blank"]
f=open("CSVSolutions.csv")
for row in csv.reader(f):
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword == row[0] or keyword == row[1]:
            print(row[2])
            break
        else:
            print ("not found")
            break
f.close
```

Comment: call the close method `f.close` -> `f.close()`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to emit the message "Not found" only when the keywords were not found in the entire file?

try this:

```
import csv
keywords=["none","blank","off","screen","blank"]
f=open("CSVSolutions.csv")

for row in csv.reader(f):
    found = False;
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword == row[0] or keyword == row[1]:
            print(row[2])
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        print ("not found")
        break

f.close()
```

The main point being that you should use another variable to track the state that you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `for.. else` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) like so:

```
for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword == row[0] or keyword == row[1]:
        break
else:
    print("not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
keywords=["none","blank","off","screen","blank"]

f=open("CSVSolutions.csv")
for row in csv.reader(f):
    if row[0] in keywords or row[1] in keywords:
        print(row[2])
    else:
        print ("not found")
f.close
```

I figured avoiding nested for entirely was easier. It may seem slower to iterate over the keywords list twice but it's basically equivalent to making two comparisons per item anyways.

Comment: Please add descriptions of your changes and/or code comments

Comment: Thanks for all the help, the last code prints out four outputs, which I wanted to avoid. I will try the others

Comment: Neither of the above worked unfortunately. The first one doesn't print anything when the keyword is found. The csv is very basic, you can imagine that the first two columns contain keywords, if they are matched that whatever is in column three is printed. Closess I get is Not found printing out 4 times. Can't see why that is. I've tried putting a break after the not found statement. Still no luck. But appreciate all the help